# pandas: how to import "horse-colic.data", a space separated data file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import "data" file [horse-colic](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Horse+Colic) dataset.

the content in the file looks like

```
2 1 530101 38.50 66 28 3 3 ? 2 5 4 4 ? ? ? 3 5 45.00 8.40 ? ? 2 2 11300 00000 00000 2
1 1 534817 39.2 88 20 ? ? 4 1 3 4 2 ? ? ? 4 2 50 85 2 2 3 2 02208 00000 00000 2 
2 1 530334 38.30 40 24 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 ? ? ? 1 1 33.00 6.70 ? ? 1 2 00000 00000 00000 1
```

this file seems not to be considered as a csv. because the piece of code

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/horse-colic/horse-colic.data', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df.replace("?", np.NaN)
df.head()
```

produces

[image]

`df.replace("?", np.NaN)` does not work at all.

any ideas?

Comment: Header = None is working, your column names are range index starting from 0. replace requires assignment or inlace = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.replace("?", np.NaN)` returns a copy of `df` with `"?"` replaced by `NaN`. To change `df` itself you'd do `df = df.replace("?", np.NaN)` or

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/horse-colic/horse-colic.data', delim_whitespace=True, header=None).replace("?", np.NaN)
```

Or, as @Vaishali says, add `inplace=True`.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say `header=None` doesn't work. When I leave it out I get a DataFrame with the first row of the Horse Colic data set as my column names.

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is one that has each item separated by commas.
I recommend using `numpy.genfromtxt`, then converting that into a data frame.

The first bit would go like this:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.genfromtxt('filename.txt',deletechars='?',filling_values=np.NaN)
```

and if you need it in a pandas data frame, that is usually a pretty smooth transition

Reference:

1. [numpy.genfromtxt - NumPy Manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html?highlight=genfromtxt#numpy.genfromtxt)