# matplotlib: why plot a hist would cause IndexError in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning [horse-colic](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Horse+Colic) dataset.

thanks to @Vaishali @Ultra TLC @Tom 's [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56013488/11074017), the data is imported.

```
p_data = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MachineIntellect/dataset.ml/master/horse_colic.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(p_data)
df = df.replace("?", np.NaN)
df = df.astype(np.float)
```

to get the number of cols and rows to plot, this piece of code works well too

```
%matplotlib inline
n_col = 4
n_row = int(math.ceil(df.shape[1] * 1.0/n_col))
```

when i try to plot a hist

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_row, n_col, figsize=(15, 30))
plt.tight_layout()
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    pos_i = i / n_col
    pos_j = i % n_col
    df.groupby("cp_data")[col].plot.hist(title=col, alpha=0.5, ax=axes[pos_i, pos_j]);
```

error shows up

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e6f18b850dfa> in <module>()
     17     pos_i = i / n_col
     18     pos_j = i % n_col
---> 19     df.groupby("cp_data")[col].plot.hist(title=col, alpha=0.5, ax=axes[pos_i, pos_j]);
     20 
     21 

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

why plot a hist would cause IndexError?

It seems that something wrong happens somewhere at [plot.hist(),](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html) how to figure it out?

Comment: I get a different error when I run your code example: `KeyError: 'cp_data'`.

Comment: pos_i and pos_j have to be integers because there are used as indices of axes.